# How to check if two neighbors (element) in a string/array are the same

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

Well basically, I'm having a problem, how to make a function in haskell to work like this:
 to take the first element of a string, then take the second one and compare them, then the function should continue with taking the third element from the string and comparing the second and the third one.

If it would have to compare the first two then the next two it would be easy, but I just can't figure it out in this particular situation.

I need to achieve this step in order to write a function which if finds two neighbor elements which are the same, returns True and if there aren't any elements like that returns False.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A higher-order way to accomplish this (i.e. no explicit recursion) is to use `zipWith` to perform a point-wise comparison of the elements in the list, starting with the first, against the elements of the list, starting from the second (using `tail`), and then using `or` to collapse the point-wise results into a single result.  You don't even need to special case the empty list since `zipWith` is non-strict in its third argument if its second argument is the empty list.

**EDIT:** Solution (hover to reveal)

> `hasNeighbors as = or . zipWith (==) as $ tail as`

Comment: Wow interesting, lazy I am, but this is still a higher level for me, but thanks anyway, will try it also this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a recursive function that solves this problem. There are 3 situations you must handle:

1. If the function gets the empty list or a list of one element, then obviously it won't contain any neighbors, so you return `False`.
2. If the list starts with two items that are not equal, then it means that it doesn't start with a neighbor pair, so you should perform the check on all of the list except for the first element.
3. If the list starts with two items that are equal, you know that the list contains a neighbor pair, so you can return `True`.

Tell me if you want me to provide the code that does this, or if you don't want any more hints.

**EDIT:** Solution (hover to reveal)

> `hasNeighbors :: Eq a => [a] -> True
> hasNeighbors (a : allExceptA @ (b : _))
>   | a == b = True
>   | otherwise = hasNeighbors allExceptA
> hasNeighbors _ = False`

Comment: allright this is exactly the point where I am stuck. I know and have defined the empty list, the single element list, and am thinking about recursion ofcourse, the problem I'm having is well:

Comment: nghbor :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
nghbor [] = False
nghbor [x] = False
nghbor (x:y:s) = if x==y then True
                        else eqngh ()

Comment: Think about what you should replace `()` with. It's all of the list except `x`, or in other words, the `s` list with `y` in front of it.

Comment: I don't know how to continue with the recursion to make it like=> y:eqngh s, or I should somehow define to take another z from the list

Comment: Try doing `eqngh (y : s)`. That will pass on all of the list except for the first `x`.

Comment: Allright, so it will continue then like y-z;z-... right? That's exactly what I wasn't sure about.

Comment: Yes, it will, that is the solution.